# Twython auth 'how to get authorized'

Tags: python, qt, twitter, tkinter, twython

I'm working on a Twitter desktop application with Twython literary and I have a problem with OAuth. How can I get an OAuth token and secret

Is the token only needed for the first time? Or will I need it every time I get tweets or status updates?

I'm using pyqt is there another GUI that is lighter and simpler to use than qt that is not tkinter?

Comment: As for Qt - either go for it, or go for Tkinter. GTK+, which is the other crossplatform major  toolkit is on the same complexity level and less capable.

Comment: You cuould try `wxPython`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to authenticate your users with 2 steps:

The begin_auth, where the user can aprove your app, and next the login_thanks screen where you can extract the data from user...

I get this working with django+twython, see more detailed info here: https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython-django/blob/master/twython_django_oauth/views.py